# Conflicting closures

Tags: discussion

[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42466/ota-updates-for-the-rpi) question about OTA updates was just asked. There are already at least 2 other questions regarding OTA updates:

[OTA Update of Multiple Raspberry Pi's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31746/ota-update-of-multiple-raspberry-pis)

[Raspberry Pi Over the Air Update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31543/raspberry-pi-over-the-air-update)

One was closed as off-topic, one was upvoted and answered. Which was the correct action, and should I flag today's question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding closures generally, [the logic explained here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/732/5538) with regard to topicality is all that can apply.  Since it is something where decisions are made by human beings, there are bound to be inconsistencies, particularly in the different minds of different people.

I've admitted elsewhere that my own attitude may appear inconsistent (and it does vary over time) but I am always happy to explain myself when asked.

"Over the air updates" is a concept so ambiguous that details are required.  It is one step away from "transfer data on the internet", which also all by itself is not a useful question.  If sufficient details are given, these should help to clarify whether it is on topic here or not.

> should I flag

If you feel that something should be flagged, flag it.  If you feel that something deserves an up or down vote, up or down vote it.  If you feel that a question should be closed or reopen, vote to close or reopen. All of these options require certain reputation levels.